# SAS: writing outfile

Tags: sas

### I would like to generate an outfile that looks like this:

MULTILOG for Windows 7.00.2327.2

Created on: 22 February 2012, 15:02:00

> PROBLEM RANDOM,

```
     INDIVIDUAL, 

     DATA = 'C:\Multilog\TACH_MATH03B_FT_MF.IDM.txt', 

     NITEMS = 65, 

     NGROUPS = 1, 

     NEXAMINEES = 63382;
```

> TEST ALL,

```
  L3;
```

> END ;

2

01

11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111

N

(T30,65A1)

---

To make like the above, I wrote this code but got some errors. what did I do wrong?

```
data _null_;
 file 'C:\Users\ubishky\Documents\TN try\dry run 2010-11\mcfmath3.txt';

 put @1 MULTILOG for Windows 7.00.2327.2;
     @1 Created on: &sysdate9, &systime;
     @1>PROBLEM RANDOM,; 
     @10 INDIVIDUAL,; 
     @10 DATA = 'C:\Multilog\TACH_MATH03B_FT_MF.IDM.txt',; 
     @10 NITEMS = 64,; 
     @10 NGROUPS = 1, ;
     @10 NEXAMINEES = 63382;
     @1>TEST ALL,; 
     @7 L3;;
     @1 >END ;;
     @1 2;
     @1 01;
     @one=REPEAT(1,63);
     @1 N;
     @1(T30,65A1);
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding PUT to the beginning of your @ statements.

Comment: oh I should have put all those text into " ". I just have one error now at put @1 one=repeat(1,63). I wanted to put 64 ones...

Comment: i got it. I had to make one=repeat("1",63) before the put statment. then put @1 one;

Comment: You can answer your own question. How about posting the final, working code.